# variable object name error

Tags: vb.net

I have the following:

- a listbox called ListBox1 with a couple of random values in it
- a couple of rich textboxs called Rit11 up to Rit 154
- a button

When I click a rich textbox, I want to set the a variable to the number that the box is called. After this I select a value from the listbox, and when I press the button, I want this value to move to the selected textbox, and be removed from the listview. I made the following code, but it gives an error.

```
Private Sub Rit12_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Rit12.Click
        SelBox = "12"
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Dim BoxName
        BoxName = ("Rit" & SelBox)

        Me.Controls(BoxName).Text = ListBox1.SelectedItem
        ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(ListBox1.SelectedIndex)


    End Sub
```

It worked fine, till I tried using the variable name. This rule seems to give the problem:

```
Me.Controls(BoxName).Text = ListBox1.SelectedItem
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! _"it gives an error"_ is unfortunately a very vague problem description as it could be any error in the entire cyberworld. Please tell us the **exact** error message you get, and since you're new here please also take a moment to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Turn `Option Strict On`...

Comment: You will also want to allow for cases when there is no selected item and controls in another container like a Panel, Tab or GroupBox